# How to send alert when a query hits certain threshold in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pii

I am trying to set up alert if someone tries to query > threshold of sensitive data(eg email) in Snowflake. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No built in functionality here. But with the content from here https://medium.com/hashmapinc/sending-email-notifications-from-snowflake-using-external-functions-4b985c182292 you can use external functions and AWS to send emails. The reason, why the email is triggered, is then your Snowflake implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake does not have this functionality built in, but it is easily extensible.
You can write functions or procedures in JAVA, Scala, Python (soon) and send notifications that way.
Or you can use an external monitoring mechanism such as [SNOWALERT](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SnowAlert-Data-Driven-Security-Analytics-using-Snowflake-Cloud-Data-Platform)

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate on how this can be done with python?